# Scrapy - Make one API request then use the data from that request to make another API request

Tags: python, api, scrapy, screen-scraping

Appreciate this is very simple, and I've managed to get the data I want using requests but for the life of me I can't seem to figure this out.

Essentially I am making a request to an API which returns a nicely formatted json that includes a load of site data for multiple sites. I then want to iterate through this list, extracting the site id nested in the json to make requests for the menus at each site. This should just be a case of passing the site id into a request along with the rest of the URL and then returning the json data that this new request generates but I cannot seem to be able to figure out how to do this.

I'm happy to offer more detail if anyone is able to help and needs it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So I've set up a basic scraper in python using scrapy that makes the first request that returns all the data for every site and then I just yield this data. I've ran it and it works fine too. The issue comes when I try to use this data to inform the second batch of requests. I'm struggling to get my head around how to pass the new list of links I've created from the info generated from the first request into a second request to then return the site specific json data that I want to investigate.